# Problems DNS Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, swarm

I have two identical Docker Swarm Cluster.

In the first cluster I can access a certain container of a service with scaling:

```
# ping -c service_http.1
PING service_http.1 (10.0.4.125): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.4.125: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.150 ms
```

But in cluster 2 the name resolutions fails:

```
# ping service_http.1
ping: bad address 'service_http.1'
```

The two cluster are with:
Docker: 20.10.8; Docker API: 1.41; Debian 11.

What can be wrong?

Thanks a lot for the help.